# How to avoid grabbing a row from a one-to-many relationship?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have three tables, with structures like this:

```
Trips: id
Users: id
users_has_trips: user_id, trips_id
```

My current query:

```
SELECT trips.id 
FROM trips 
LEFT JOIN users_has_trips ON users_has_trips.trips_id = trips.id 
WHERE users_has_trips.users_id != '1'
```

I would like not to select a trip.id if the value in `users_has_trips.users_id` is set to a certain value (such as 1). `users_has_trips` has multiple rows with the same values for `users_has_trips.trips_id` so when I eliminate the row that has the undesired users_id, I will still have rows showing up.

For example, there are trip.id values of 1 and 2. users_has_trips columns (trips_id, users_id) have values of (1, 1), (1, 2), and (1, 3), respectively.

When I run the query above, WHERE will eliminate the the row for (1, 1), but will still grab the trips.id of 1 in rows (1, 2), (1, 3), and also the trips.id of 2.

The desired outcome is to not select trips.id value of 1 (because my users_id was associated with it) and only grab trips.id value of 2.

Comment: Are you saying you want to select all trips that user 1 is not a part of?

Comment: Your current query excludes rows where `users_has_trips.user_id != '1'` already (although the usual syntax is `<>` instead of `!=`). Please post sample data, the results you expect to get from that data, and the wrong results you're getting from your current query. ALso, it's highly unlikely that you're using both mysql and sql-server at the same time - please only add the tags for the **specific** DBMS you're using, and don't just add those that seem like they contain familiar words. Tags here have specific meaning, and the accurate DBMS is important because of syntax and feature differences.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to select all trips that user 1 is not a part of.But being that the users_has_trips table shows many rows of a trip (as many times as other users are part of the trip) I'm having troubles not looking at those rows as well.

Comment: Your question is more unclear now than it was before your edit. Now you're saying you want to exclude those rows where `trips.id` equals 1, where before it was `users_has_trips.users_id`. Once again, please post (in tabular form) *sample data* and the *results you want to obtain from that data*. Note I said *in tabular form*, where it looks like a table, so that it makes some sense, and in the process clarify what you want in the results so that there's some consistency. As it is now, I haven't a clue what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Point me in a direction on how to use a "tabular form" and I gladly will. I'm having troubles finding the format to get the output you want.
As for the question, I don't know how to make it any more clear. I don't want trips.id of 1 because users.id was associated with it. But I still get trips.id of 1 because users.id of 2 and 3 are still linked with trips.id of 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM trips AS t
WHERE t.id NOT IN
 (
   SELECT trip_id
   FROM users_has_trips 
   WHERE user_id = '1'
 )
```

Or rephrasing your question:

Only show those trips where no row exists for a given user:

```
SELECT * 
FROM trips AS t
WHERE NOT EXISTS
 (
   SELECT *
   FROM users_has_trips AS ut 
   WHERE ut.user_id = '1'
     AND ut.trip_id = t.id
 )
```